# C# How to get location of smaller image inside larger image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am new to image processing so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying the come up with a way to get the co-ordinates of a sub image inside that of its containing larger image. For example, I have a large image of the [New York skyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dfES.jpg) and one of just the [Empire State building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brpub.jpg). The large picture is always a high quality image, the small picture is supplied by a user's camera scanning a printed version of the larger image. There the quality, scale and colors of the smaller image will not perfectly match those of the larger one. What I am looking to get is X, Y coordinates from the top-left corner of the larger image, to the top-left corner of the smaller image as if the smaller image were a puzzle piece placed in the larger image. It would be much appreciated of someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

**EDIT**
Thank you for the feedback. I have come to realize that this might be a very difficult task. I ended taking a different approach. I will be embedding recognizable shapes in the aforementioned print media and use OpenCvSharp (a free C# wrapper around OpenCV) to detect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to just give you one possible direction,

What you are might be facing here is a flavor of pattern detection and/or recognition (aka machine learning), I suggest look for ready implementations as this is complicated task.

The basic idea is that you train or teach an algorithm about features of objects of interest and then the algorithm searches in images for anything that matches your pattern.

There are many algorithms out there; each will have its own approach. As a starting point, You could try to look at what well known image processing framework can offer - OpenCV:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

EDIT : 
OpenCV wrapper for .NET C# as OpenCV is C++ project

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I marked this as the solution since it pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using OpenCvSharp instead of Emgu as it is free.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hard and big project to do.

BTW, You can get color of a pixel by GetPixel() method.

Following code creates a 200x200 image and get color of 100,100 coordination of that image.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200,200);
Color c = bmp.GetPixel(100,100);
```

For surfing image efficiently you must use pointer(unsafe code) not GetPixel() method unless the performance will be too slow.